# How to refresh JPanel when JRadioButton is select?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jradiobutton

i have this class:

```
public class TF extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JRadioButton rdbtnFilm;
    private JRadioButton rdbtnSerieTv;
    private JPanel pnlGeneral;
    private JPanel pnlRadioButton;
    private JLabel lblTitolo;
    private JTextField tfTitolo;

    public TF() 
    {   
        pnlGeneral = new JPanel();
        pnlRadioButton = new JPanel();

        rdbtnFilm = new JRadioButton("Film");
        rdbtnFilm.addActionListener(this);
        pnlRadioButton.add(rdbtnFilm);
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnFilm);

        rdbtnSerieTv = new JRadioButton("Serie Tv");
        rdbtnSerieTv.addActionListener(this);
        pnlRadioButton.add(rdbtnSerieTv);
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnSerieTv);

        pnlGeneral.add(pnlRadioButton, gbc_panel_1);
        this.add(pnlGeneral);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(rdbtnFilm.isSelected())
        {
            lblTitolo = new JLabel("Titolo");
            pnlGeneral.add(lblTitolo, gbc_lblTitolo);

            tfTitolo = new JTextField();
            tfTitolo.setColumns(10);
            tfTitolo.setText("1");
            pnlGeneral.add(tfTitolo, gbc_tfTitolo);
        }

        if(rdbtnSerieTv.isSelected())
        {
            lblTitolo = new JLabel("Titolo");
            pnlGeneral.add(lblTitolo, gbc_lblTitolo);

            tfTitolo = new JTextField();
            tfTitolo.setColumns(10);
            tfTitolo.setText("1");
            pnlGeneral.add(tfTitolo, gbc_tfTitolo);
        }
    }
}
```

but when i select a radio button just sometimes JPanel show me JLabel and JTextfield. I don't know if i need use revalidate(), repaint() or something else to refresh JPanel.
This happens because Swing isn't thread-safe?

***Update***

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
              public void run() 
              {
                  JFrame gui=new GUI();
                  gui.setVisible(true);
                  gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                  gui.setSize(800,720);
              }
        });
    }
}


public class GUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
    private boolean selected=true;
    public GUI()
    {   
        //Creazione del Menu
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Switcha");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menu.addMouseListener(this);
        this.add(new TF());
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(selected)
        {
            this.getContentPane().removeAll();
            this.getContentPane().add(new TF());
            // do something else
        }
        else
        {
            this.getContentPane().removeAll();
            this.getContentPane().add(new TF2());
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). IMHO it perfectly suits your problem.

Comment: Because your guide use javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()?

Comment: Because of this: [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: @dic19 i have update my post. I already use Thread in main class. You think i need use it again in TF class?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't undesrtand your last update. Please see my answer. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *This happens because Swing isn't thread-safe?*

No, this happens because you are adding components to an already displayed container, causing the components hierarchy be invalidated. See [Container#add(Component comp)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-) docs.

> *I don't know if I to need use `revalidate()`, `repaint()` or something else to refresh `JPanel`.*

Yes, as per previous point. The tipical sequence in this case is:

```
panel.add(someComponent);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

---

#### Is there another way to accomplish this?

Yes, it is. As I've stated in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644778/how-to-refresh-jpanel-when-jradiobutton-is-select#comment40070102_25644778), IMHO [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) is the proper way to go through. See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) tutorial.

In a nutshell:

- Keep your panel with radio buttons.
- Have two different panels: one for films and another one for TV series.
- Have another `JPanel` with `CardLayout`.
- Add these two panels (or many as needed) as cards.
- On radio buttons change just switch the right "card" for the card layout panel.